# How to move emails from Outlook sent items to other folder based on mail subject using vba code? Thanks

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I want to move my emails from sent items to another folder based on the subject contains "Drive 20-Feb-23" using vba code.

I want to move my emails from sent items to another folder based on the subject contains "Drive 20-Feb-23" using vba code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method which moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder.

To find items with a specified subject you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. The simplest DASL syntax may look like that:

```
sFilter = "[Subject] = 'Drive 20-Feb-23'"
```

But a better approach would be to use a substring matching mechanism instead:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Drive 20-Feb-23'"
```

Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the messages to go to a different folder immediately after you send them? Trap the `Application.ItemSend` event (the item being sent will be passed to your handler), check the subject or any other appropriate condition, and set the `MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder` property to the appropriate folder from the same (!) store.